# How does attack speed affect Entropy's true damage active?

Tags: league-of-legends

Entropy is a dominion-only item with the [following description](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/items#3184):

> +275 Health +70 Attack Damage UNIQUE Passive: Your basic attacks have a 25% chance to reduce your target's Movement Speed by 30% for 2.5
>   seconds. UNIQUE Active: For the next 5 seconds, your basic attacks
>   reduce your target's Movement Speed by 30% and deal 80 true damage
>   over 2.5 seconds (60 second cooldown)

I'd like more specifics regarding the mechanics of the true damage from the active ability.  How is the damage distributed over time?  16 damage every .5 sec?  40 damage every 1.25 sec?  More importantly, does it stack?

Lets say I'm Yi and have an attack speed of 2.0 attacks per second.  Will I get 800 true damage (from 10 attacks, stacking), 224 damage (16 true damage from the first tick of the dot for each of the first 9 attacks, plus 80 for the final attack), or something in the middle?

Comment: It's supposed to mimic the Red Buff, so I'd look to see how that interacts with attack speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am making the assumption that this ability works in the same way as Teemo's poison. They are mechanically the same in that they apply a DoT on autoattack, so that seems like a reasonable assumption. If that is true, the answer is:

In the middle. Over the 5 seconds, you will deal 16*10=160 damage due to time based stacks. That is to say, a 16 damage proc occurs every .5 seconds. You will also deal 16*9 for each individual hit after the first, because hitting triggers an instant 16 damage proc in addition to refreshing the time. You will still deal the rest of the 80 from the last hit, so an additional 64 damage. In total, if you attack for 5 seconds at 2.0 hits/second, you will deal 304 damage and have 64 more damage dealt over the next 2.5 seconds, adding to a total of...

**386 true damage.**

If you want the source for that calculation, go find the RIOT explanation of teemo's buff/bugfix a couple months ago. They made it clear that you deal damage based on the time of effect, plus one tick of damage based on each individual hit.

It is possible that the mechanics are different from Teemo's poison and the 16 damage may not be applied on hit. That would make the damage equal to 240.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying that each attack will get get 2 ticks of the DoT.  The first happens immediately with the attack, and the next happens .5 sec later.  If I'm attacking faster than that, though (.2 sec between attacks) won't the DoT timer get reset before the 2nd tick?

Comment: The DoT timer doesn't reset per se, it just gets lengthened (for teemo at least). So if you have .2 seconds left till a DoT tick, and hit the enemy with poison, you extend the poison to a full 4 (2.5 in this case) seconds, but the next DoT tick still applies after .2 seconds, not .5. Hitting the player again does not lengthen the time until next DoT tick. (it used to, but that was fixed)

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense, both in this context and for the Teemo fix.  All of our math is based on the 5 ticks @ 16 damage figure - are we sure that's the correct rate of the DoT?  If it's 2 ticks @ 40, then all of these numbers change.

Comment: Its every half second, 90 percent sure. :).

Comment: @EricGrunzke I have just confirmed that it is 2 ticks of 40. Sorry to prove you wrong, Lawton. :/

Comment: Its good someone checked then :S

Comment: @QAvenDreamer, thanks for investigating! Do you remember if the first tick proc'd immediately on hit?  Or if there was a delay before the first tick?  I.e. [(hit+40), 1.25s delay, 40] or [hit, 1.25s delay, 40, 1.25s delay, 40]?

Comment: @EricGrunzke Unfortunately, it was mid-game, so by the time I noticed the two white ticks of 40 pop up, I was already running from Singed. I'll try to test under more controlled conditions soon.

Answer (score 0):

No. It states that it is unique. They should not stack.

Comment: My understanding is that the UNIQUE keyword applied to multiple copies of an item.  E.g. purchasing 2 copies of entropy will not allow you to active them both and double your true damage.  But a single activation still procs many times.  The exact effect of those procs is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Eric While his answer isn't what you were looking for, but it does point out that your question title is poorly worded. Maybe you should change it to "How does high attack speed affect Entropy mechanics" or something like that. Your title really does sound like you want to use 2 Entropies, which isn't what you mean.

Comment: Good point.  I've changed the title to (hopefully) be more descriptive.